# how to build and sign release apk in IONIC 2

Tags: android, automation, ionic2

I need to release a signed apk of my ionic 2 project. Here is official documentation for [publishing an app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html). but here I need to manually sign my unsigned apk generated by `cordova build --release android`. Is there a way to automate these steps so that signed apk can be produced in one step? I have found a blog post [here](http://ionichelper.forlearning.net/ionic-2-building-a-release-android-apk/). but it is not working for me and giving error **Failed to read key alias_name from store** "alias_name" is my actual alias_name.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue is now resolved as it was just a problem with my alias_name password. it is working fine now as described in the [tutorial](http://ionichelper.forlearning.net/ionic-2-building-a-release-android-apk/). For anyone reading this, just a side note that alias_name password is same as the keystore password.

Comment: These two passwords aren't necessarily the same. They are just what you set when you created the keystore and the key. Apparently you've just chosen the same password for both :-)

Comment: the tutorial link is broken!